# django+nginx+gunicorn - subdomain joy

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, gunicorn

i'm trying to setup **django** on **nginx + gunicorn** on a centos6 server (firewall off, selinux disabled). the project works locally on the server (tested running gunicorn on 127.0.0.1:8221), but not on the whole network. the project should be accessible from a subdomain **project.mydomain.com**

the project itself is located on a server **centos6.mydomain.com** and the dns server is **main.mydomain.com**

my **ngnix conf** for the **project**:

```
upstream project {
    server 127.0.0.1:8221 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name project.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project.mydomain.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.mydomain.com.log;

    root /home/USER/djangosites/project;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        if (!-f $request_filename){
            proxy_pass http://project;
            break;
        }

        }
    location /media  {
        alias /home/USER/djangosites/project/media;
        }
    location /static  {
        alias /home/USER/djangosites/project/static;
    }
}
```

**nginx conf** for the **centos6** (working)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name centos6.mydomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/centos6.mydomain.com.access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/centos6.mydomain.com.error.log;

        location / {
                root /var/www/centos6.mydomain.com;
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

**gunicorn conf**

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "127.0.0.1:8221"
logfile = "/home/USER/djangosites/project/gunicorn.log"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

would i be better off giving a new ip (to the outside) to the project that is different from **centos6.mydomain.com** or i can just use the same ip with different local port?

how should i configure **hosts.db** on **main.mydomain.com** then?

```
centos6   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.220
project   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.221
```

or

```
centos6   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.220
project   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.220:8221
```

or

```
centos6   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.220
project   CNAME   centos6
```

i'm kind of more inclined to give a new ip because everything is behind a m0n0wall, so a new ip could perhaps be easier to manage.

so basically, i'm guessing that my nginx conf for the project is flawed. what should i do with it?

Comment: why not rule out nginx by first pointing it to an empty directory with a index.html and see if it serves that. Once you have that working you will know that it's a gunicorn problem and after that that its an application problem. It shouldn't matter what IP you are coming in on as long as it's the IP of the machine nginx is running on. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @pastylegs since i can access the site locally (tested using curl)

    **"curl 127.0.0.1:8221"**

and nginx serves servers main static site just fine (see my centos6 nginx conf) i'm still guessing that something between nginx and gunicorn gets messed up.

this rules out gunicorn not being able to run my app on 127.0.0.1:8221 or anywhere else. so the app is running just fine, so no problem there.

about the errors... using curl i just get

    **"curl: (7) couldn't connect to host"**

Comment: just editing projects nginx conf, adding upstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. got it working :)
**hosts.db** on main.mydomain.com

```
project   CNAME   centos6
```

gunicorn runnig on 127.0.0.1:8221
and edited the nginx conf as stated above.

Comment: After 3 years posting this problem still very useful. It guide me to solve same problems as yours.